# Why don't I need to CFRetain() the result of ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID() in this code

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to work with the adress book, but my understanding of memory management is so-so at best.

My project is using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), but as I've learned, ARC only manages retain/release in Objective-C land.

I understand that my first function call: `ABAddressBookCreate()` returns an ABAddressBookRef that I "own", because I'm getting it from a method with `Create` in the name.  I `CFRelease` it when I'm done with it.

**What I don't understand** is how the ABRecordRef stays alive during the course of this method.  Shouldn't I have to `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` it?   I have another nearly identical method in the same class that was crashing if I didn't retain/release the `ABAddressBookRef`.

```
    ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();    
    ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(iPhoneAddressBook, self.addressBookRecordID);

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

    ABMultiValueRef phoneRef = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    // Set up an NSArray and copy the values in.
    NSArray *phoneNumberArray = (__bridge_transfer id)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneRef);


    CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);

    // Finally, do stuff with contact information in Obj-C land..
```

**Exit question**: have I created a leak by not calling `CFRelease` with my `ABMultiValueRef phoneRef` on the last line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with Core Foundation memory management, you want to refer to [these ownership policies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

The key to your question lies in the "Get Rule", which states that any CF* object you get from and Core Foundation function that contains the word "Get", you don't own it and can't guarantee it's lifespan. The important distinction is between "can't guarantee validity" and "isn't valid". It's possible for you to have a reference to an object that you don't own, but whose lifespan is being supported by some other source. In that case, you'll still be able to use it without crashing.

That's technically what's happening with your `ABRecordRef`. You haven't taken ownership of it, but it's extremely likely that the `ABAddressBookRef` that you're getting the record from *does* own it, and is therefore keeping it alive. As long as that `ABAddressBookRef` is valid, its records will also be valid. If you were to call `CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);` and then attempt to use the record, I'm betting it would explode.

Finally, for your exit question - Yes, you're leaking the `ABMultiValueRef` per the "Create" rule, which states that you own objects received via functions containing "Create" or "Copy".

Comment: Thanks so much.  So just for clarity, I SHOULD retain/release the ABRecordRef, even though the code is working fine at the moment. Yes?

Comment: @MattH. It's a bit subjective. The very safest approach would be to add the retain/release to avoid a potential bug that would pop up if you ever refactored that code and destroyed the address book before finishing with the record. Brevity would suggest that you just remember what's going on and omit the retain/release, since it is safe to do so with the way that you currently have the code set up.

Comment: I think that in general, regardless if the object is being owned elsewhere or not, he should claim ownership before using the object and relinquish it when done; This has the advantage of not making any assumptions/relying on external code (that might change) and makes clear the intent.

Comment: @ranReloaded, If he needed to reference that record outside of the current scope, I would agree with you unconditionally. As it stands, that's still probably good advice to keep yourself out of trouble in every situation, but I know I certainly don't retain every CF* object I ever need to use for a couple lines and then forget about. If I know they're owned by some other CFObject that I _do_ own, I prefer to keep the clutter down.